# Managing and reporting on Java Maven dependencies across all source projects for a large project

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Is there a tool to manage, track and report on all library dependencies across a number of Java source projects that are using Maven?

Using Maven to manage build time dependencies works well, but given a large number of source projects (say 50) each with it's own Maven pom.xml, is there any tool or product that can be used to answer questions like

- what is the entire set of libraries used across all our source
  projects?
- what versions of libraries are we using?
- are we consistently using version x of library y across all source projects,
  or do we have an consistent mix of library versions in use?

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of such a tool. What you can do:

1. Use `dependency:list` on each project and compare/combine the results (write a script for that).
2. Use BOMs. These are good for managing versions of dependencies. You can list all usual dependencies with versions and import the BOM in all your projects so that you get the same set of versions everywhere.
3. Combine your separate projects into a multi-module project. Then you can fix versions in the parent pom and also have more leverage to analyze and influence versions.

Comment: #1 is an option, and something we've used up until this point. #2 would have been viable from the start of the project, but now with different projects already managing their own dependencies with potentially different library versions, introducing BOMs now would be non-trivial. For #3 we do already have related projects structured as multi-module projects, but for unrelated projects this wouldn't make much sense (in our case at least)

Answer (score 0):

For a project I use where I compile code and gather the dependencies. It is a python script to take all the files that contain the full maven output of dependency:list for each project. This was designed just to allow me to load the dependencies to run a program but you could modify the script to do nicer things with the set of dependencies

#!/usr/bin/python3

```
from os import listdir

from os.path import isfile, join

files = [join("deps/", f) for f in listdir("deps/") if isfile(join("deps/", f))]

allParts = []

#Need to exclude all.dep
for entry in files:
    print("Considering: ", entry)
    if entry == "deps/all.dep":
        continue
    f = open(entry, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
#   for line in lines:
#       if line.startswith("[WARNING]"): continue
#       if line.startswith("Down"): continue
    if(entry == "deps/dockhorn.dep"):
        print(lines)
    parts = lines[-1][:-1].split(":")
    print(parts)
    allParts.extend(parts)
s = set(allParts)
print("\n".join(s))

f = open("deps/all.dep", 'w')
f.write(":".join(s) + "\n")
f.close()
```